# Looping through all child elements to wrap it in one parent element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, for-loop

I have this HTML markup:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="background">
     <div class="a">Title</div>
     <div class="b">Subtitle</div>
     <div class="c">Footer</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="background">
     <div class="a">Yet another title</div>
     <div class="b">Yet another subtitle</div>
     <div class="c">Yet another footer</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="background">
     <div class="a">One last title</div>
     <div class="b">One last subtitle</div>
     <div class="c">One last footer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am aiming to wrap all the divs (the a, b, c) below the `background` div using `.wrap()`. But somehow, when I used this code:

```
var backgrounds = document.getElementsByClassName("background");
for(var i = 0; i < backgrounds.length; i++) {
   var childs = backgrounds[i].childNodes;
   $(childs[i]).wrap("<div class='allthedivs'></div>");
}
```

Well, it doesn't work the way I expected. Instead of wrapping all the child divs, it turned out into something like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="background">
    <div class="allthedivs"></div>
    <div class="a">Title</div>
    <div class="b">Subtitle</div>
    <div class="c">Footer</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="background">
     <div class="allthedivs"><div class="a">Yet another title</div></div>
     <div class="b">Yet another subtitle</div>
     <div class="c">Yet another footer</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="background">
     <div class="a">One last title</div>
     <div class="allthedivs"></div>
     <div class="b">One last subtitle</div>
     <div class="c">One last footer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there anything I'm doing wrong here? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You need .wrapAll: https://jsfiddle.net/k9npdc63/

Answer (score 0):

To wrap all the children of each background element in the same div using jQuery, you can use the `wrapAll()` function. Here's an example of how you can achieve it:

```
$('.background').each(function() {
  $(this).children().wrapAll('<div class="allthedivs"></div>');
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$('.background').each(function() {
  $(this).children().wrapAll('<div class="allthedivs"></div>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="background">
    <div class="a">Title</div>
    <div class="b">Subtitle</div>
    <div class="c">Footer</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="background">
    <div class="a">Yet another title</div>
    <div class="b">Yet another subtitle</div>
    <div class="c">Yet another footer</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="background">
    <div class="a">One last title</div>
    <div class="b">One last subtitle</div>
    <div class="c">One last footer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```